# Numpy find maximum tuple in array of windows

Tags: python, numpy

I'm starting our with list of tuples (each tuple is an (X,Y)). My end result is I want to find the maximum Y-value within EACH window/bin of length 4 using numpy.

```
# List of tuples
[(0.05807200929152149, 9.9720125), (0.34843205574912894, 1.1142874), (0.6387921022067363, 2.0234027), (0.9291521486643438, 1.4435122), (1.207897793263647, 2.3677678), (1.4982578397212543, 1.9457655), (1.7886178861788617, 2.8343441), (2.078977932636469, 5.7816567), ...]

# Convert to numpy array
dt = np.dtype('float,float')
arr = np.asarray(listTuples, dt)
# [(0.05807201, 9.97201252) (0.34843206, 1.11428738)
#  (0.6387921 , 2.02340269) (0.92915215, 1.4435122 )
#  (1.20789779, 2.36776781) (1.49825784, 1.9457655 )
#  (1.78861789, 2.83434415) (2.07897793, 5.78165674)
#  (2.36933798, 3.14842606) ...]

#Create windows/blocks of 4 elements
arr = arr.reshape(-1,4)
# [[(0.05807201, 9.97201252) (0.34843206, 1.11428738)
#   (0.6387921 , 2.02340269) (0.92915215, 1.4435122 )]
#  [(1.20789779, 2.36776781) (1.49825784, 1.9457655 )
#   (1.78861789, 2.83434415) (2.07897793, 5.78165674)]
#  [(2.36933798, 3.14842606) (2.95005807, 2.10357308)
#   (3.24041812, 1.15985966) (3.51916376, 2.03056955)]...]

print(arr.max(axis=1)) <-- ERROR HERE
print(max(arr,key=lambda x:x[1])) <-- ERROR, tried this too but doesn't work
```

Expected output I want from each window/blocks using max y-value is below. Alternatively format could be regular list of tuples, doesn't strictly need to be numpy array:

```
[[(0.05807201, 9.97201252)]
[(2.07897793, 5.78165674)]
[(2.36933798, 3.14842606)]...]
OR other format:
[(0.05807201, 9.97201252),(2.07897793, 5.78165674),(2.36933798, 3.14842606)]...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a vectorized (and probably fastest) approach:

```
arr = np.asarray(listTuples, np.dtype('float,float'))
idx = arr.view(('float',2))[:,1].reshape(-1,4).argmax(1)
arr = arr.reshape(-1,4)[np.arange(len(idx)),idx]
#[(0.05807201, 9.9720125) (2.07897793, 5.7816567) ...]
```

You basically use a array (non-structured) version of your structured array by `view` and find argmax of Y along `axis=1`. Then use those indices to filter the tuples from your original array `arr`.

Answer (score 1):

this should solve your issue.

Input: list of tuples

Ouput: list of tuples, taking the the tuple with the maximum y-value in each block
of 4 elements
import numpy as np

```
# List of tuples
listTuples = [(1,1),(120,1000),(12,90),(1,1),(0.05807200929152149, 9.9720125), 
(0.34843205574912894, 1.1142874), (0.6387921022067363, 2.0234027), 
(0.9291521486643438, 1.4435122), (1.207897793263647, 2.3677678), 
(1.4982578397212543, 1.9457655), (1.7886178861788617, 2.8343441), 
(2.078977932636469, 5.7816567)]


def extractMaxY(li):
    result = []
    index = 0
    for i in range(0,len(li), 4):
        max = -100000
#find the max Y in blocks of 4
        for j in range(4):
            if li[i+j][1] > max:
                max = li[i+j][1]
                index = i+j
        result.append(li[index])
    return result


print(extractMaxY(listTuples))
```

The output is then

```
[(120, 1000), (0.05807200929152149, 9.9720125), (2.078977932636469, 
5.7816567)]
```

as it should be, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```py
import numpy as np
ans = []
for value, comp in zip(x, np.max(x, axis=1)[:,1]):
    ans.append([(i, j) for i, j in value if np.isclose(j,comp)])
print(np.array(ans))
```

applying this on your data

```py
x =  np.array([[(0.05807201, 9.97201252), (0.34843206, 1.11428738),
  (0.6387921 , 2.02340269), (0.92915215, 1.4435122 )],
 [(1.20789779, 2.36776781), (1.49825784, 1.9457655 ),
  (1.78861789, 2.83434415), (2.07897793, 5.78165674)],
 [(2.36933798, 3.14842606), (2.95005807, 2.10357308),
  (3.24041812, 1.15985966), (3.51916376, 2.03056955)]])
```

**Returns**

```py
[[[ 0.05807201  9.97201252]]

 [[ 2.07897793  5.78165674]]

 [[ 2.36933798  3.14842606]]]
```